# Spring MVC 3: Define own Datatype-Binding

Tags: java, spring-mvc

in a spring3 Controller I can create an action-method with several Parameters witch will be set by spring

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateTemplate")
public void doStuff(HttpServletRequest request, Locale locale) {
  assert request != null;
  assert locale != null;    
}
```

How can I teach Spring to fill my own defined Data-Types?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateTemplate")
public void doStuff(HttpServletRequest request, Locale locale, MyClass myClass) {
  assert myClass != null;
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what you want but a step in the direction you might want to take http://karthikg.wordpress.com/2009/11/08/learn-to-customize-spring-mvc-controller-method-arguments/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use [WebArgumentResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/WebArgumentResolver.html)

```
public class MyClassWebArgumentResolver implements WebArgumentResolver {
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter param, NativeWebRequest req) throws Exception {
        if (param.getParameterType().equals(MyClass.class)) {
            MyCLass obj = new MyClass();
            ....
            return obj;
        }
        return UNRESOLVED;
    }

}
```

and register it to springmvc:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven >
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
       <bean class="com.xxx.MyClassWebArgumentResolver" />
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

then you can use it in your controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateTemplate")
public void doStuff(HttpServletRequest request, Locale locale, MyClass myClass) {
    assert myClass != null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring has a class called [`HttpMessageConverter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) that will do just this for you.  It will take various members of the incoming `HttpServletRequest` and use them to create an object that will then be passed to your `Controller` methods.  The best part is that it will do this automatically for you if you have the `HttpMessageConverter`'s added into the `ApplicationContext` (via the `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`, described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-message-conversion)).

There are many prebuilt implementations that exist already, and you can find a lot of them on the `HttpMessageConverter` page linked above.  Probably the most often helpful are [`MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.html), which is used to map a JSONObject from the request body to a JavaBean, and [`MarshallingHttpMessageConverter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/MarshallingHttpMessageConverter.html), which is used to map XML from the request body to a JavaBean.

Comment: Seems not to be the thing im searching for, WebArgumentResolver was the right hint